# How to reduce time complexity of MST using fibonacci heap's union operation?

Tags: time-complexity, minimum-spanning-tree, fibonacci-heap

I am searching for linear time complexity of **MST**. I am trying to proceed this using **Fibonacci heap** as its union and find minimum operation takes constant time. Is possibly there any link to reduce time complexity of MST?
Please help.

Comment: Prim's algorithm?

Comment: actually I am trying to make linear time complexity for finding MST. I found this fibonacci heap whose Find-minimum() operation takes 0(1) time. Now I am interested whether there is a possiblity to improve time complexity using this operation or not?

Comment: Prim with Fibonacci is O(E+V log V), But if the Graph is sparse can be O(E+log log V)]

Comment: Fibonacci Heaps are theoretically better than Binary Heaps. But their the constant factors hidden are very [high](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31196753/10311208)